# Creating a payload array for items in cart

Tags: javascript

I have a system that allows to add some items to cart [array]. Items are just `objects` with some data and I would like to access some specific `properties` from each item and would like to create a new `array` that has new `items` with those `properties`. The code provided below works but only if the cart has one item. I would like to make it work for many items in cart. How to achieve it?

```
this.cart.forEach((item) => {
  // if cart had only one item it would work
  // I need to somehow create a array that contains `payload object` for each item.
  let payload = {
    name: item.name,
    amount: item.amount,
    price: item.price
  }
  return payload
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Method to achieve it.

```
let payloads = this.cart.map((item) => {
    return {
        name: item.name,
        amount: item.amount,
        price: item.price
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've actually used your method after seeing it.

Answer (score 4):

```
let payloads = []; //create array

this.cart.forEach((item) => {
  //push to array
  payloads.push({
    name: item.name,
    amount: item.amount,
    price: item.price
  })
})

console.log(payloads);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `forEach` in this situation. `forEach` executes the callback function on each item of the array and it doesn't care about what the function returns. Instead, your function should work correctly with `map`(similar to what cheekujha answered), it constructs a new array with the elements you return from each callback return.